# me marca error en mi proyecto ¿como se soluciona?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache

[image: bombitas][image: caso]

¿porque no se marcan? o que estoy haciendo mal aun soy muy novato para esto

Comment: Es mejor copiar y pegar código que pasar una imagen .Que error te marca el IDE?. Importaste las librerías necesarias para la conexión a tu base de datos?'

Comment: ¿y que mensaje de error te muestran las bombillitas que marcan el error cuando pones el ratón encima?

Comment: No repitas preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529817/me-da-estos-errores-y-no-se-como-arreglarlos-apache-netbeans, gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [me da estos errores y no se como arreglarlos -Apache Netbeans-](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529817/me-da-estos-errores-y-no-se-como-arreglarlos-apache-netbeans)

Comment: ya puse lo que me arrojan las bombitas amigo y perdon xc

Comment: Diria que las comillas que usas en esas dos primeras lineas con errores son un poco raras... si te fijas en las sentencias entrecomilladas de esas lineas la inclinación de las comillas de apertura y las de cierre son distintas, como si lo hubieras pegado de alguna parte con ese formato.  Prueba de borrarlas a mano y volverlas a poner, y comprueba si su aspecto ha cambiado y si se solucionan esos errores.

Comment: pues tu segundo PrepareStatement es llamado upd  usala con ese nombre no ´up´  y despues de print falta ;

Comment: Falta el caracter ")" de cierre para el print ya que el "}" es del try-catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es, [como indica masterguru en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/263200/masterguru), que las comillas usadas no son las correctas en algunas partes.

**Usa la comilla simple (alt+39).**